# MySQL Regex for matching exactly 3 same chars but not 4 same chars within a larger string

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to write a regex for mysql in PHP to find (at least one occurrence of) exactly 3 of the same characters in a row, but not 4 (or more) of the same.

Eg for "000" I want to find:

- 0//////0/00/  LS///////**000**
- **000**////0/00/  LS//////////
- 0//////0/00/  LS////**000**///
- 0//////**000**//  LS//////**000**/
- 0//////**000**//  LS//00000000

but not:

- 0//////**000**0/  LS//////////
- 0//////0**000**/  LS//////////
- 0/////0**000**0/  LS//////////

I have tried the code below which I thought would match 3 zeros preceded and followed by zero or more chars which are not 0, but this resulted in some rows with single 0's and some 000000's

```
REGEXP '[^0]*[0{3}][^0]*'
```

Many thanks.

Comment: You can use [word boundaries](http://makandracards.com/makandra/921-word-boundaries-in-mysql-regular-expressions): `SELECT 'mystr' REGEXP '[[:<:]]000[[:>:]]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to use a regex in MySQL, you cannot use lookarounds. Thus, you can use alternation with negated character class and anchors:

```
(^|[^0])0{3}([^0]|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mF1dE7/2)

Explanation:

- `(^|[^0])` - a group matching either the start of string (`^`) or a character other than `0`
- `0{3}` - exactly 3 zeros
- `([^0]|$)` - a group matching either a character other than `0` or the end of string (`$`).